# Primary DB failover to backup MongoDB instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, database

My Rails app runs primarily on a regular mySQL database, however, if this database goes down I would like the Rails app to failover to a MongoDB database which is basically just a 'cached' version of the primary database.

Some ideas I had were two models (AR and MongoDB - using Mongoid) and then catching exceptions in the controllers and using the MongoDB models if the primary fails, but I feel like that would be too cluttered having two models of everything. Another idea was (and I haven't tested) rescuing database connection exceptions in the model and using the model as a MongoDB one instead but thinking about it, if the model originally inherits from ActiveRecord::Base there might be issues.

What would be a good approach to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any good way to have a failover between MySQL and MongoDB, and to be honest I'm not too fond of the idea.

Why not make your MySQL Backend failsave with a few slaves?

Comment: How woud you have it failover to a slave?  Rails only allows one db listed in database.yml and automatically connects to it at start.  If that's down, the process won't start...